# How to write a function to record groups Input

Tags: scala

I want to write a function that will record the input for each group and then display their input. For example,

Group Input:

```
groupOneInput = a, b, c

groupTwoInput = i, j, k
```

how many groups:

```
numOfGroups = 2
```

Current solution:

```
import scala.io.StdIn._

def x(numOfGroups: Int): String = {
  (
    if(numOfGroups <1) "Done"
    else {
      println("\nPlease enter your values:\n")
      val input = readLine
      input + x(numOfGroups-1)
    }
  )
}
```

output:

```
String = String = a, b, ci, j, kDone
```

desired output:

groupOne = a, b, c

groupTwo = i, j, k

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def x(numOfGroups: Int): Unit = {
     def y(numOfGroups:Int):String =
       if(numOfGroups <1) "Done"
        else { println("\nPlease enter your values:\n")             
               val input = readLine
               input + y(numOfGroups-1)
             }
    val t = y(numOfGroups).dropRight(4).mkString.replaceAll(",","").
      replaceAll(" ","").grouped(3).toList.map(x=>x.mkString(","))
    val x = List("groupOne","groupTwo").zipWithIndex
    for((i,j)<-x) println(i+" = "+t(j))
  }
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> x(2)

Please enter your values:a,b,c
Please enter your values:i,j,k
groupOne = a,b,c
groupTwo = i,j,k

scala> x(2)

Please enter your values:a, b, c
Please enter your values:i, j, k
groupOne = a,b,c
groupTwo = i,j,k

scala>
```

Comment: @Thanks RAGHHRAAMM.